# How I can get the hyperlinks to pass their names as POST variables?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to create a form with hyperlinks. When clicked, they submit the page and pass different values.

Here's my code:

```
<script language="Javascript">

function submitForm(action){

document.forms["MyForm"].innerHTML = 
    document.forms["MyForm"].innerHTML 
    + "<input type=hidden name=submit value='" + action +"'>";

document.forms["MyForm"].submit();

}

</script>


<form name="MyForm" action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="abc" value="" />
<a name="edit" href="javascript:void(1);" onClick="submitForm('Edit');">Edit</a>

<a name="delete" href="javascript:void(1);" onClick="submitForm('Delete');">Delete</a></form>
```

---

When I click on href link, I get the error

```
document.MyForm.submit is not a function
[Break On This Error] document.MyForm.submit();
```

Anyone know why this error occurs?

Comment: WHY SO COMPLICATED?? do u want to edit/ delete a post ??

Comment: i must agree, there are better ways to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. It's because of `name='submit'` in `<input type=hidden name='submit' value='" + action +"'>`. You change this to make it work:

Try this:

```
<script>
function submitForm(action)
{
document.forms["MyForm"].innerHTML = 
    document.forms["MyForm"].innerHTML 
    + "<input type=hidden name='submit1' value='" + action +"'>";

document.forms["MyForm"].submit();
}

</script>


<form name="MyForm" id="MyForm" action="config.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="abc" value="" />
<a name="edit" href="javascript:void(1);" onClick="submitForm('Edit');">Edit</a>

<a name="delete" href="javascript:void(1);" onClick="submitForm('Delete');">Delete</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much man. its doing now. plz let me know why you change name = 'submit1'...? :)

Comment: i have also face this problem earlier but i do'nt knw the exact reason behind this.

Answer (score 1):

Use id="MyForm" instead of name="MyForm"...

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<script>
function setAndSubmit(text){
document.getElementById('submit').value=text;
document.forms["MyForm"].submit()
}
</script>

<form name="MyForm" id="MyForm" action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="abc" value="" />    
<input type="hidden" name="submit" id="submit" value="" />
<a name="edit" href="#" onClick="setAndSubmit('Edit')">Edit</a>
</form>
```

Comment: same error occur document.MyForm.submit is not a function [Break On This Error] document.MyForm.submit();